# Ansible take vmware snapshot

Tags: ansible

I've been reading the vsphere_guest docs and it seems to fit my use case in a lot of ways, but it's not clear to me how I would take a VM snapshot?

How would one go about safely upgrading VMs in VCenter in an Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little late at this point, but wanted to point it out if anyone else was looking for this.

There has been a module introduced that will let you take a snapshot.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vmware_guest_snapshot_module.html

I'm playing around with it currently.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no module (core or extras) to create a VMWare snapshot. There was a request for this feature under extras but it looks like the person [who submitted the feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/7690/) never followed through with submitting it to the extras modules for Ansible.

This means you would have to take a snapshot of your VM in vSphere prior to using Ansible to upgrade your VMs. There are likely other ways to automate the snapshot process without Ansible however I am not familiar with that. You can view all the VMWare extras modules in github: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/tree/devel/cloud/vmware

Comment: Two years ago?! At least it's a start.